# Using if an AWK command

Tags: command-line, awk

I have a file which contains many sub-sections each starting with [begin] and ending with [end]sample of which is shown below:

```
[begin li1_1378184738754_91]
header=7075|lime|0|0|109582|0|1|2700073||0|0|0|[355]|1|0|ssb-li1-1378184738754-90||0||LIME |0|saved=true|0.002406508312038836|0|[ser=zu1:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=uzu6:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=xzs5:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=sv-stda-zu3:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=hzu8:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=lzu3:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=yzu2:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=xzu7:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer]|0|null|false|40||false|
attrs=0|0|0||0|
ptitle=690751404|1|1|1|Rest:1998636||||||2700401|175619|900.5636134725806|0.985486|39.166666666666664|$9.99|100.0|1|||
seller=1998636|1|9.99|1|-1||0|||||true||4.7937584|10412|false|
ptitle=5543369186|2|1|1|Rest:1533891||||||2700211|19615|886.8211044369053|0.776121|34.0|$119.99|100.0|1|||
seller=1533891|1|119.99|3|-1|1.0:text,In+size+6.0%2C7.0%2C8.0%2C8.5%2C9.0%2C9.5%2C10.0%2C...,0.0,,,,0,0,|2|||||true||2.95|20|true|
ptitle=622529158|3|1|1|||||||2700408|67402|796.5289827432475|0.893899|63.0|$5.27|100.0|1|||
seller=4281413|1|5.27|1|-1||0|||||true||4.695052|1769|true|
ptitle=5507199621|4|1|1|||||||2700220|56412|706.9031281251306|0.791171|45.0|$99.99|100.0|1|||
seller=4806107|1|-1.0|1|-1|1.0:sale,$,30.000000000000014,0.0,,,,0,0,:text,In+size+6.0%2C6.5%2C7.0%2C7.5%2C8.0%2C8.5%2C9.0%2C9...,0.0,,,,0,0,|2||||$130 $30.00 off|false||5.0|1|false|
ptitle=5502728013|5|1|1|||||||900000|0|698.7772340643119|0.836740|75.0|$40.95|100.0|1|||
seller=955448|1|40.95|1|-1||0|||||false||4.142857|7|false|
ptitle=840662011|6|1|1|Rest:265238||||||300233|62718|683.2927820751431|0.995513|52.0|$22.95|100.0|1|||
seller=265238|1|22.95|1|-1||0|||||false||4.478261|23|false|
ptitle=848084980|8|1|1|||||||2700073|145653|670.4809846773688|0.880587|60.0|$24.99|100.0|1|||
seller=5267046|1|24.99|1|-1||0|||||true||0.0|0|false|
ptitle=891200492|9|1|1|Rest:1030132||||||2701003|17215|668.8437575254773|0.825491|32.0|$519.99|100.0|1|||
seller=1030132|1|519.99|1|-1||0|||||false||4.7391305|23|false|
ptitle=641974054|10|1|1|||||||900000|69433|667.6678790058678|0.752129|57.0|$4.19|100.0|1|||
seller=3365158|1|4.19|1|-1||0|||||true||4.70907|4410|true|
ptitle=517591869|12|1|1|Rest:4802895||||||2700408|127644|643.0972570735605|0.893899|17.25|$23.95|100.0|1|||
seller=4318776|1|-1.0|3|-1||0|||||false||0.0|0|false|
ptitle=541549480|13|1|1|Rest:1180414||||||2702000|105832|597.4904572011968|0.752129|24.666666666666664|$8.27|100.0|1|||
seller=4636561|1|8.27|1|-1||0|||||false||4.8283377|734|true|
ptitle=1020561900|14|1|1|||||||2700063|159813|594.4717491579845|0.934869|75.0|$5.39|100.0|1|||
seller=4722645|1|5.39|1|-1|1.0:sale,$,0.6000000000000005,0.0,,,,0,0,:text,Free+Shipping+on+All+Orders%21,0.0,201301010000/,,,0,0,|2||||$5.99 $0.60 off|true||4.3942246|1593|true|
ptitle=507792308|15|1|1|Rest:4683455||||||2702000|105832|591.7739184402442|0.768311|22.5|$9.48|100.0|1|||
seller=4910651|1|-1.0|2|-1||0|||||false||5.0|1|false|
ptitle=1090571346|16|1|1|Rest:4452919||||||2700211|20824|776.4814913363535|0.776121|35.0|$59.99|100.0|1|||
seller=1533891|1|59.99|1|-1|1.0:sale,$,49.99999999999999,0.0,,,,0,0,:text,In+size+7.5%2C8.0%2C8.5%2C9.0%2C9.5%2C10.0%2C10.5...,0.0,,,,0,0,|2||||$110 $50.00 off|true||2.95|20|true|
ptitle=573017390|17|1|1|||||||2700073|91937|679.695660577044|0.880587|33.5|$14.85|100.0|1|||
seller=4281413|1|14.85|1|-1||0|||||true||4.695052|1769|true|
ptitle=5502723300|18|1|1|||||||900000|0|639.3095640940136|0.836740|75.0|$50.95|100.0|1|||
seller=955448|1|50.95|1|-1||0|||||false||4.142857|7|false|
ptitle=940022974|20|1|1|||||||2700600|58701|569.9503499778303|0.875839|59.0|$14.40|100.0|1|||
seller=4825227|1|14.4|1|12||0|||||true||4.0289855|276|true|
ptitle=5513277553|21|1|1|||||||2700220|56412|565.2712749001105|0.776121|44.33333333333333|$129.95|100.0|1|||
seller=4825252|1|129.95|1|23||0|||||true||4.0289855|276|true|
ptitle=890329961|22|1|1|||||||2700408|133796|564.7642425785796|0.837916|34.75|$61.95|100.0|1|||
seller=4825235|1|61.95|4|19||0|||||true||4.0289855|276|true|
ptitle=753852910|24|1|1|||||||2700073|146738|557.7419123688652|0.934869|47.69230769230769|$26.99|100.0|1|||
seller=4722645|1|26.99|10|-1|1.0:sale,$,3.0,0.0,,,,0,0,:text,Free+Shipping+on+All+Orders%21,0.0,201301010000/,,,0,0,|2||||$29.99 $3.00 off|true||4.3942246|1593|true|
ptitle=654738989|26|1|1|||||||900000|84012|554.7756559595525|0.752129|57.0|$3.19|100.0|1|||
seller=3365158|1|3.19|1|-1||0|||||true||4.70907|4410|true|
ptitle=707747307|27|1|1|Rest:4736009||||||2700063|76249|552.234395428327|0.889614|19.857142857142854|$6.39|100.0|1|||
seller=4736009|1|6.39|1|-1||0|||||false||4.8071113|15356|true|
ptitle=63531001|28|1|1|||||||2700408|82712|625.0421885589608|0.893899|47.166666666666664|$7.69|100.0|1|||
seller=4281413|1|7.69|3|-1||0|||||true||4.695052|1769|true|
ptitle=5502728016|29|1|1|||||||900000|0|605.9895507237038|0.836740|75.0|$503.00|100.0|1|||
seller=955448|1|503.0|1|-1||0|||||false||4.142857|7|false|
ptitle=507792308|31|1|1|Rest:4683455||||||2702000|105832|559.6902659046442|0.752129|22.5|$8.99|100.0|1|||
seller=5105812|1|-1.0|1|-1||0|||||false||0.0|0|false|
ptitle=753852910|32|1|1|||||||2700073|146738|545.9987095658629|0.870929|47.69230769230769|$22.49|100.0|1|||
seller=4143386|1|22.49|6|-1|1.0:sale,$,7.5,0.0,,,,0,0,:text,Free+Shipping+on+Orders+Over+%24100,0.0,201109010000/201409302359,,,0,0,|2||||$29.99 $7.50 off|false||4.7316346|2355|true|
ptitle=5513277553|33|1|1|Rest:1533891||||||2700220|56412|653.3133907916089|0.825491|44.33333333333333|$149.99|100.0|1|||
seller=1533891|1|149.99|3|-1|1.0:text,In+size+5.0%2C5.5%2C6.0%2C6.5%2C7.0%2C7.5%2C8.0%2C8...,0.0,,,,0,0,|2|||||true||2.95|20|true|
ptitle=63531001|34|1|1|||||||2700408|82712|541.8233547780552|0.893899|47.166666666666664|$7.72|100.0|1|||
seller=2370155|1|7.72|4|-1||0|||||false||4.85|40|false|
ptitle=1018957017|35|1|1|||||||2700073|145653|540.6093714604533|0.860614|56.0|$25.95|100.0|1|||
seller=5036683|1|25.95|1|-1||0|||||false||4.8405056|366|false|
ptitle=743682867|36|1|1|||||||2700073|63437|539.5985846455641|0.870929|58.0|$46.99|100.0|1|||
seller=193176|1|46.99|1|-1||0|||||true||4.8511987|1418|true|
ptitle=679858288|37|1|1|||||||2700063|188669|535.1360632897284|0.902031|30.0|$12.41|100.0|1|||
seller=4143386|1|12.41|2|-1|1.0:sale,$,1.379999999999999,0.0,,,,0,0,:text,Free+Shipping+on+Orders+Over+%24100,0.0,201109010000/201409302359,,,0,0,|2||||$13.79 $1.38 off|false||4.7316346|2355|true|
ptitle=994328713|38|1|1|||||||2700073|71463|534.7715925279717|0.870929|58.0|$1.29|100.0|1|||
seller=1787388|1|1.29|1|-1||0|||||false||4.680464|3624|false|
ptitle=886915818|40|1|1|||||||2700444|201835|529.7519801432289|0.934869|65.5|$44.99|100.0|1|||
seller=4561883|1|44.99|2|-1||0|||||true||4.7913384|508|false|
seller_hidden=227502|990765963|1147436601|-1
seller_hidden=5310958|622529158|5645627277|-1
seller_hidden=4825254|5543369186|5651114316|23
seller_hidden=5289138|5548930281|5653769481|-1
[end li1_1378184738754_91]
```

I am trying to run the command `cat /home/nextag/logs/OutpdirImpressions.log.2013-09-02 | awk -F "$begin" '{print $0}' | awk '$0 ~ "header=7075" {print $0}'`
As per this command i want to split the entire file into sub-sections beginning with the word 'begin'. Now in that i want those sub-sections which contains 'header=7075'

Expected output is that it will print the entire sub-section(those which contain that string), but i am getting only this portion as output:

> header=7075|lime|0|0|109582|0|1|2700073||0|0|0|[355]|1|0|ssb-li1-1378184738754-90||0||LIME
>   |0|saved=true|0.002406508312038836|0|[ser=zu1:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=uzu6:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=xzs5:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=sv-stda-zu3:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=hzu8:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=lzu3:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=yzu2:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer][ser=xzu7:mtu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:mu=model_other_20120806calibex.csv:scorerClassUsed=LinearPersonalizedProductSearchScorer]|0|null|false|40||false|

I have tried using if in various ways, but it doesn't works. Can somebody please help me. 
I tried `awk -F "$begin" '{if($0 ~ "header=7075") {print $0}}' /home/nextag/logs/OutpdirImpressions.log.2013-09-02`. It gave the same result

Can somebody please suggest that how do i get the complete sub-section in the result

Comment: If you have more to add, please do it by editing your question, not leaving dozens of comments.

Comment: sorry about that, but you could have let me add there before deleting them :(

Comment: Can you explain more clear what output do you expect?

Comment: I want the whole sub-section as output, the file contains many such sub-sections each starting with [begin] and ending with [end]

Comment: actually i want to split the whole file into sub-sections beginning with [begin and ending with [end. And in those sub-sections i want to filter out the sub-sections that contain 'header=7075'.

Comment: @vipin8169: To understand your code: Please what do you have in the `begin` variable? You are using it to set a field separator of `awk`.

Comment: yes, i am using it as a field separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the one liner solution for the same:-

```
awk '$1=="[end"{p=0}/^header=7075/{p=1}p' file
```

or `sed '/^\[end/G' input.txt | awk -vRS='' '/header=7075/'`

both servers the purpose

Answer (score 3):

### Awk script - section delimiters not passed + comments

This variant does not pass the `[begin ...]` and `[end ...]` delimiters.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN   {
    insect=0    # we are out of a section
    }

/^\[begin [a-z0-9_]+\]/ {
    insect=1    # section opening
    next
    }

insect == 1 {
    if($0 ~ /^header=7075\|/)   {
        insect=2    # we are inside the right section
        }
    else    {
        insect=0    # we are in a different section
        next
        }
    }

/^\[end [a-z0-9_]+\]/ && (insect == 2 || insect == 1)   {
    exit 0      # end of the right section -> stop processing
    }

insect == 2 {
    print       # we are inside the right section -> pass all lines
    }
```

### Awk script - section delimiters passed + contracted code

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {ins=0}
/^\[begin [a-z0-9_]+\]/ {beg=$0; getline; if($0 ~ /^header=7075\|/) {print beg; ins=1}}
/^\[end [a-z0-9_]+\]/ && ins {print; exit 0}
ins
```

**as one-liner :)**
I do not understand the demand for one-liners but here it is:

```
awk 'BEGIN {ins=0} /^\[begin [a-z0-9_]+\]/ {beg=$0; getline; if($0 ~ /^header=7075\|/) {print beg; ins=1}} /^\[end [a-z0-9_]+\]/ && ins {print; exit 0} ins'
```

The advantage of the programs in this answer is that they process the input line-by-line as is usual in Unix utilities. This makes the program to be able to process very log sections without extreme memory demands and allows the program to run in parallel (on multi-core CPUs) with other programs in a pipe.

Comment: This doesn't print the `begin` and `end` lines, is this intended?

Comment: @moon.musick: Yes, that is intentional. I understood the question that only content of a section should be passed. This code is processing the input line by line and is able to process extremely long sections without high memory requirements. It is also piping-friendly - allows parallel processing with other components in a pipe thanks to the line-by-line passing. :)

Comment: I see ;) I have to get to know awk better, I know it can handle very complex text processing tasks.

Answer (score 2):

#### Bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

section=""
insect=0
while read line
    do if [ "$insect" -eq "1" ] || [ "x$(echo -e $line | grep '\[begin')" != "x" ]; then
        insect=1
        section="${section}${line}\n"
    else
        continue
    fi
    if [ "x$(echo -e $line | grep '\[end')" != "x" ]; then
        if [ "x$(echo -e $section | grep 'header=7075')" != "x" ]; then
            echo -e "$section"
        fi
        section=""
        insect=0
    fi
done < OutpdirImpressions.log
```

#### Python script

(better performance than bash)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

section = ''
insect = False
with open('OutpdirImpressions.log', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if line == '':
            break
        if insect or line.startswith('[begin'):
            insect = True
            section += line
        else:
            continue
        if line.startswith('[end'):
            if 'header=7075' in section:
                print(section)
            section = ''
            insect = False
```

Comment: Both your programs pass a text before the `[begin ...]` section delimiter.

Comment: You're right. I thought this wouldn't be an issue because vipin8169 didn't avoid that either in his examples. I fixed this but anyways your awk script is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this answers your question at all, i.e. whether you are interested in 'whatever works' or much rather in `awk`-specific answer, but it seemed to me you want a oneliner (not that these examples are very wieldy):

```
python3 -c "import re; print(*[rec for rec in re.findall('(?ms)\[begin.*?(?=\[begin|\Z)', open('OutpdirImpressions.log.2013-09-02').read()) if 'header=7075' in rec])"
```

and for Python 2.6 or 2.7 (no 'star' unpacking for all I remember):

```
python -c "import re; print([rec for rec in re.findall('(?ms)\[begin.*?(?=\[begin|\Z)', open('OutpdirImpressions.log.2013-09-02').read()) if 'header=7075' in rec][0])"
```

Comment: As I know very little about python and this code is not understandable for me I tested it. Unfortunately I discovered some problems: The python3 code is passing text after the `[end ...]` delimiter. The python 2.x code shows syntax error in python 2.7.3 on `*` after `print(`.

Comment: @pabouk fixed the typo, there definitely should be no `*`. Perhaps we're working on different sample files - I copied the 'section' provided by the OP to a file several times, modifying the `header=xxxx` part - the command prints only the correct 'section', so I assumed it works ok enough. The code is a bit convoluted, as I wanted to make a oneliner - basically it divides the file into sections using regex with lookahead and then makes a list of the sections, but filtering out 'incorrect' sections. Python doesn't let you squeeze much logic into one line (and does it on purpose).

Comment: The sample file from the question is not a good representation of what is described in the question. It does not contain text before and after the only section in it. I copied and pasted some lines before and after the section to be able to test the begin and end conditions in my script.

Comment: @pabouk The lookahead in the regex I used expects either another `[begin` or end of file (`\Z`) as the end of section. If I had more data about text before and after 'sections' part, I could add it to the alternative in the lookahead.